# Faced the error x is not a function with prototypes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I am new to JavaScript and was learning prototypes in JavaScript and I faced the error:

> main.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: bmw.move is not a function

with the following code:

```
function Car() {
  this.model = 'BMW';
  this.speed = 1000;

  Car.prototype.move = function () {
    alert('Move the car');
  }
}
function BMW() {

}

BMW.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);
let bmw = new BMW();
bmw.move();
```

Comment: There are a couple of errors in the above. You should never assign a function to `Car.prototype` from *within* a call to `Car`. The inheritance relationship between `BMW` and `Car` is only half-implemented. See the linked question's answers for how to properly set up an inhertance relationship using constructor functions, either in ES5 or (since it's 2019) using `class` syntax.

Comment: function Car() {
      this.model = 'BMW';
      this.speed = 1000;
    }
      Car.prototype.move = function () {
        alert('Move the car');
      }

    function BMW() {

    }

    BMW.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);
    let bmw = new BMW();
    bmw.move();

Comment: @Anilm - No, that's still missing at least two pieces, please see the linked question's answers.